# CSS scroll only middle element of three

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get, in pure CSS, a vertical layout where the first element is always on the top, the third element is always on the bottom, and the second one is in the middle.

The 3 elements shall fill 100% of the height of their parent element, without overflowing and without overlapping.

All of the elements can change their sizes. So using fixed positioning is not feasible, I think, because when the bottom element expands, the middle one shall change its height accordingly.

Also, I would like to have the middle one to scroll when content does not fit.

Now, I tried few different approaches without success:

- using `fixed` positioning is not adjusting **middle element** height when bottom element resizes,
- using `flex` I cannot make the middle element to scroll when they overflow.

I recently found out about `sticky` positioning, and this looks like a possible use case for it, but I am not sure how.

How can I achieve this positioning scheme?

EDIT: here's a fiddle to give you the idea:

https://jsfiddle.net/f4scm02y/1/

I would like the blue part being constrained by the red and green parts, with the top and bottom elements free to be resized without causing overlaps.

Comment: Have you got an example on jsFiddle or Codepen and/or can you post it?

Comment: I'll make it right away.

Comment: Actually, it appears that sticky is exactly what I need, but... Browser support is lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

#container {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically */
  height: 100vh; /* just for demo */
  background-color: #FFF;
}

#top {background-color: #FCC}

#middle {
  background-color: #CFC;
  overflow: auto; /* recommended */
  flex-grow: 1; /* grows and takes all the remaining vertical space */
}

#bottom {background-color: #CCF}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    Top has variable height<br/>
    but usually rather short.
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
          Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
        Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
          Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
        Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
          Middle has variable height<br/>
    and usually it is pretty long.<br/>
    This content must be scrolled<br/>
    and it should expand as much<br/>
    as possible.<br/>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud<br/>
    exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip<br/>
    ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <br/>
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit<br/>
    esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br/>
    Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,<br/>
    sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt<br/>
    mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    Bottom has variable height<br/>
    but usually rather short.
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to make the `#middle` *div* flexible with `flex-grow: 1` or just `flex: 1` (shorthand).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i'm understanding correctly, but if you just want the red to always be on top, the green to scroll and the blue to always be on the bottom without the green overlapping you can simply remove the

```
position:absolute;
```

from the #bottom CSS.

like this:

```
#bottom {
  background-color: #CCF;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I did not think of that solution, but the problem is that the containers will actually overflow their parent: https://jsfiddle.net/f4scm02y/2/

Comment: @AkiRoss I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve? Do you want the green one to scroll on scroll? Also you can remove the fixed height from the body class.

Comment: I needed exactly what @VXp did :) Thanks anyway! (btw no, the height is fixed)